# Alternative method to display content

Tags: javascript, jquery

The selected radio button will show its corresponding dropdown box.

For example, upon the selected radio button ‘Ontario’, a dropdown box with matching cities will show up.

I have the following working code for the above example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#searchForm input:radio").change(function() {

      var buttonPressed = $('[name="Region"]:radio:checked').val();
      var cityElmntBox = document.getElementById("dispalyCityBox");

      if(buttonPressed == 'Ontario'){
          cityElmntBox.style.display='block';
      } else {
          cityElmntBox.style.display='none';
      }

  });   
});
</script>
```

Instead of the sudden effect (`display='block'`), I wanted to use for the selected elements the `slideDown()` method.

So I replaced:

```
cityElmntBox.style.display='block';
```

with:

```
cityElmntBox.slideDown(500);
```

But this doesn’t work…, please can someone help me get it working?

Comment: `dispalyCityBox` -> sure you don't have a typo here? Anyway don't mix jQuery and raw js when dealing with DOM, use `$()` selectors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$('#dispalyCityBox').slideDown(500)` instead.

By using `cityElmntBox.slideDown(500);` you're trying to use a jQuery method on a non-jQuery object.

Comment: Working! Thank you very much for your help, quick response and professionality.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in jQuery:

```
$(cityElmntBox).slideDown(500);
```

Also you can simplify the var statement like this and you wont have to put it in a wrapper:

```
var cityElmntBox = $("#dispalyCityBox");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$('#dispalyCityBox')` instead of `document.getElementById("dispalyCityBox")`.